# How do I fix this multiline regular expression in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, multiline

I have a regular expression in Ruby that isn't working properly in multiline mode.

I'm trying to convert Markdown text into the Textile-eque markup used in Redmine.  The problem is in my regular expression for converting code blocks.  It should find any lines leading with 4 spaces or a tab, then wrap them in *pre* tags.

```
markdownText = '# header

some text that precedes code

    var foo = 9;
    var fn = function() {}

    fn();

some post text'

puts markdownText.gsub!(/(^(?:\s{4}|\t).*?$)+/m,"<pre>\n\\1\n</pre>")
```

Intended result:

```
# header

some text that precedes code

<pre>
    var foo = 9;
    var fn = function() {}

    fn();
</pre>

some post text
```

The problem is that the closing *pre* tag is printed at the end of the document instead of after "fn();".  I tried some variations of the following expression but it doesn't match:

```
gsub!(/(^(?:\s{4}|\t).*?$)+^(\S)/m, "<pre>\n\\1\n</pre>\\2")
```

How do I get the regular expression to match just the indented code block?  You can test this regular expression on Rubular [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/1FHPzR8En5).

Comment: Why not include newline in your regex: `((?:\s{4}|\t).*?\n)+`

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Mladen Jablanovic I couldn't get your example to work using this code: `puts markdownText.gsub!(/((?:\s{4}|\t).*?\n)+/,"<pre>\n\\1\n</pre>")`.  How would `\n` behave differently from `$`?

Comment: That was just the regex to get the indented part (tried it in Rubular), not a complete working gsub-ready solution (hence, just a comment).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, note that `'m'` multi-line mode in Ruby is equivalent to `'s'` single-line mode of other languages. In other words; `'m'` mode in Ruby means: *"dot matches all"*.

This regex will do a pretty good job of matching a markdown-like code section:

```rb
re = / # Match a MARKDOWN CODE section.
    (\r?\n)              # $1: CODE must be preceded by blank line
    (                    # $2: CODE contents
      (?:                # Group for multiple lines of code.
        (?:\r?\n)+       # Each line preceded by a newline,
        (?:[ ]{4}|\t).*  # and begins with four spaces or tab.
      )+                 # One or more CODE lines
      \r?\n              # CODE folowed by blank line.
    )                    # End $2: CODE contents
    (?=\r?\n)            # CODE folowed by blank line.
    /x
result = subject.gsub(re, '\1<pre>\2</pre>')
```

This requires a blank line before and after the code section and allows blank lines within the code section itself. It allows for either `\r\n` or `\n` line terminations. Note that this does not strip the leading 4 spaces (or tab) before each line. Doing that will require more code complexity. (I am not a ruby guy so can't help out with that.)

I would recommend looking at the markdown source itself to see how its really being done.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments ridgerunner.  I think yours was the only answer so far that actually worked to my specs out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

/^(\s{4}|\t)+.+\;\n$/m

works a little better, still picks up a newline that we don't want. 
[here](http://www.rubular.com/r/YxLpna3lfg) it is on rubular.

Comment: saw ridgerunner's post after I posted this, definitely a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.rubular.com/r/O6cEBBEMkk)'s another one that captures all the indented lines in a single block

```
((?:^(?: {4}|\t)[^\n]*$\n?)+)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me with your sample input.

```
markdownText.gsub(/\n?((\s{4}.+)+)/, "\n<pre>#{$1}\n</pre>")
```