# Match all lines prefixed with four spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to wrap all lines that are prefixed with 4 space chars with `pre` tags. This is what I have so far

```
Text = Text.replace(new RegExp("( {4}.+?)<br />", "g"), "$1\n");
Text = Text.replace(new RegExp("( {4}.+?)\n", "g"), "<pre class=\"brush: js;\">$1</pre>");
```

It works but it wraps every line in a `pre`. I need it to wrap the whole block.

Comment: Should your regexp start with a ^, in case there are 4 of more spaces in the middle of a line?  I know doesn't help your question, just thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this would work? It matches multiple lines in a row..

```
( {4}.*(\n {4}.*)*)\n
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to do this with regular expressions? Regexes are cool and useful but they're not the only tool in your toolbox and sometimes it is best to do something straight forward and move on to real problems. I'd just bust it into lines and parse it line-by-line with an accumulator for the things that need to be pre-ified:

```
var lines = text.split('\n');
var pre   = [ ];
var out   = [ ];
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
    if(lines[i].match(/^    /)) {
        pre.push(lines[i]);
    }
    else if(pre.length > 0) {
        out.push('<pre>' + pre.join('\n') + '</pre>' + '\n');
        out.push(lines[i]);
        pre = [ ];
    }
    else {
        out.push(lines[i]);
    }
}
if(pre.length > 0) {
    out.push('<pre>' + pre.join('\n') + '</pre>' + '\n');
}
text = out.join('\n');
```

That may not be as clever as an incomprehensible regex but at least you'll be able to understand what it is doing six months down the road.

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tFNyv/

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
Text = Text.replace(new RegExp("(( {4}.+?\n)+)", "g"), "<pre class=\"brush: js;\">$1</pre>");
```

Assuming the 
 replacement has already been done.

It worked for:

```
    lalalal
    noway it's block1
    greetings

    foobar
    block2
    indeed block2
```

And produced, line breaks are hidden :

```
<pre class="brush: js;">    lalalal
    noway it's block1
    greetings
</pre>
<pre class="brush: js;">    foobar
    block2
    indeed block2
</pre>
```

Comment: OP says: It works but it wraps every line in a pre. I need it to wrap the whole block.

Comment: Yes and the OP didn't say what a block is, so I assumed a block is broken by something not being an element of a block. As long as he doesn't answer my comment I won't change the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$.each(text.split('\n'), function(index, value)
{
    var t = value.replace(/^[\s]{4}(.*)$/, "<pre>$1</pre>");
    $("body").append(t);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jotapdiez/zx8Pg/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the questioner wants to do a markdown-like conversion. This question is similar to this one: [How do I fix this multiline regular expression in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719353/how-do-i-fix-this-multiline-regular-expression-in-ruby/5719838#5719838). If the desired effect is to mimic markdown code conversion, consider the following (adapted from my accepted answer to the ruby question):

```js
var re = /(\r?\n)((?:(?:\r?\n)+(?:[ ]{4}|\t).*)+\r?\n)(?=\r?\n)/mg;
text = text.replace(re, '$1<pre class="brush: js">$2</pre>');
```